# Шифрование паролей пользователей

Tags: база-данных, sql, шифрование, mysql

Привет.
Интересует какой тип шифрования используется для паролей юзеров, которые хранятся в таблице user?

Можно ли поменять тип шифрования пароля пользователя?

Как узнать пароль юзера?

P.S.: Задача стоить узнать пароль а не сменить...
Спасибо за идеи...

Comment: используется измененный SHA1, изменен специально чтобы таблицами не подобрать было. узнать - перебором, тонкости реализации алгоритма смотрите в исходниках mysql.

Comment: Ты имеешь в виду стандартную таблицу или просто в БД? )

Comment: SHA и другие хэши - это не шифрование, а криптографическое  преобразование. В частности, оно обязано обладать и обладает свойством необратимости. Т.е. по значению хэш-функции подобрать исходный пароль вычислительно невозможно

Comment: @regenerator но можно подобрать подходящий :)

Comment: Успехов вам в этом нелегком деле. Есть 2 пути - китайская лотерея и канадский квантовый компьютер. В первом случае может помешать недостаток знания языка, во втором - недостаток денег

Comment: Багодарен  eicto , renegator .Моя цель была не взлом БД...

Answer (score 1):

Это хэш функции,обладающие свойством необратимости...Примерно надо представлять из чего состоит пароль и тоже хешировать,потом сравнивать хэш ответ.Так и подберёшь,иначе никак.
md5,sha1 в основном используются,хотя md5 устарел.

Comment: Кроме необратимости, криптографические хэши необходимо обладают свойством стойкости к коллизиям. А значит хэши 2 очень похожих паролей будут иметь принципиально разные значения хэша. Лавинный эффект